# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error LUCENE

Tags: java, sql-server, apache, solr, lucene

Hello I am working on Lucene to index my database records but I am unable to solve this error.

**Error:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       Directory cannot be resolved to a type
>       The method open(Path) in the type FSDirectory is not applicable for the arguments (File)
>   
>       at lucene.Lucenetest.main(Lucenetest.java:32)

**CODE:**

```
    package lucene;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.SimpleAnalyzer;
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.DateTools;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.DateTools.Resolution;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
    import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
    import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
    public class Lucenetest {
//database connection
    public static final String PATH = "C:/dbindex/index.txt";
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "jjdbc:sqlserver://WMDENTW1\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;" + 
                        "database=FullTextDB;" + 
                        "user=root;" + 
                        "password=root123";
    private static final String QUERY = "select FTID, ID, CLASSID, TEXT, PUBNOTICECONTENT, DOCUMENTCONTENT, contentSum_DE from METADATA_FULLTEXT";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Lucenetest indexer = new Lucenetest();

//error here

    ***Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.open(new File(PATH));***

    try{  
//index writer
       Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();  

       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL); 

       StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();  

       IndexWriterConfig Config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

       IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir, Config);  

       System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + indexDir + "'...");  

       int indexedDocumentCount = indexer.indexDocs1(indexWriter, conn);  

       indexWriter.close();  

       System.out.println(indexedDocumentCount + " records have been indexed successfully");

    } catch (Exception e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
    } 
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int indexDocs1(IndexWriter writer, Connection conn) throws Exception {  
      String sql = QUERY;  
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);  
      int i=0;
      while (rs.next()) {
```

//checking for null and allowing it to add

```
        String FTID = resultSet.getString("FTID"); //!= null ? resultSet.getString("FTID"): " ";
        String ID = resultSet.getString("ID")!= null ? resultSet.getString("ID"): " ";

        String CLASSID = resultSet.getString("CLASSID")!= null ? resultSet.getString("CLASSID"): " ";

        String TEXT = resultSet.getString("TEXT")!= null ? resultSet.getString("TEXT"): " ";

        String PUBNOTICECONTENT = resultSet.getString("PUBNOTICECONTENT")!= null ? resultSet.getString("PUBNOTICECONTENT"): " ";
        String DOCUMENTCONTENT = resultSet.getString("DOCUMENTCONTENT")!= null ? resultSet.getString("DOCUMENTCONTENT"): " ";

                String contentSum_DE = resultSet.getString("contentSum_DE")!= null ? resultSet.getString("contentSum_DE"): " ";

         Document d = new Document();  
         d.add(new Field("FTID", rs.getString("FTID"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
         d.add(new Field("ID", rs.getString("ID"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED ));
         d.add(new Field("CLASSID", rs.getString("CLASSID"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

           if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE) {
        // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be there):
        System.out.println("adding " + FTID + " ---- " + ID + "---- " + CLASSID);
          writer.addDocument(doc);

        }

        }

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says that Lucenetest can't be compiled.
The reason is FSDirectory expects `java.nio.file.Path` but receives incompatible `java.io.File`. 

Looks like the code was developed for previous version of Lucene which accepted File https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html. The recent Lucene versions expect Path https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html.

The solution is to change line with error to

```
 Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.open(new File(PATH).toPath());
```

Comment: Yeah! thanks I didn't notice it, now its working but have a problem with JDBC connection

Comment: I see misprint in `CONNECTION_URL = "jjdbc:sqlserver://WMDENTW1\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;"` Try to remove extra "j".

Comment: The code is working but I am getting an error and also I couldn't see the indexed files using LUKE..
ERROR:
Indexing to directory 'MMapDirectory@C:\dbindex lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@4493d195'...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value cannot be null

 at org.apache.lucene.document.Field.<init>(Field.java:238)
 at org.apache.lucene.document.Field.<init>(Field.java:960)
 at lucene.Lucenetest.indexDocs1(Lucenetest.java:80)
 at lucene.Lucenetest.main(Lucenetest.java:56)

Comment: @SravanguptaK. `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown from `org.apache.lucene.document.Field` constructor. It contains null check for value passed in `value` param. So you need to check values that come from DB. Looks like some of them is null.

Comment: Yeah true some values are null some how I sorted it out but I am geeting one more exceptional error, as my database values are more than the string limit lucene cannot index so what to do and how?

Comment: @SravanguptaK Overcoming string field limit doesn't look simple. Try approach described here [Solr string field type max indexable characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255742/solr-string-field-type-max-indexable-characters)

Comment: but I was using lucene right could I change my above code as per the described approach???

Comment: HERE IS THE ERROR: UNABLE TO SOLVE
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document contains at least one immense term in field="DOCUMENTCONTENT" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[80, 69, 71, 65, 83, 79, 83, 32, 72, 97, 110, 100, 98, 117, 99, 104, 32, 73, 32, 71, 114, 117, 110, 100, 102, 117, 110, 107, 116, 105]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 56530
1151 total milliseconds

Comment: @SravanguptaK Probably you need to create separate question with relevant title and description. So more people can see it and help. What you asking here is far from original question.